# Android material design glitch

Tags: android, button, material-design

There is problems when using `RectangleButton` in this andriod material design library : https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary
when i touch the button and scroll it leave something that won't go if you don't click on the button
image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nu7G.jpg

xml code

```
<com.gc.materialdesign.views.ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <view
        class="com.it.university.lbu.ecogallery.EcoGallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false">

            <view
                class="com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ff5146ff"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:text="General&#10;   Blog"/>

            <view
                class="com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
                android:background="#ff67ce00"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:text="Branch&#10;  Blog" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <view
                class="com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:id="@+id/view3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ff0aff00"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:textColor="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:text="Personal&#10;    Blog"  />

            <view
                class="com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:id="@+id/view4"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ff007ad4"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:text="My Friend"  />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <view
                class="com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:id="@+id/view5"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffff0000"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:text="My Teacher"  />

            <view
                class="com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:id="@+id/view6"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffc1ff00"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:text="Last News"
                android:textColor="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a 2 solutions for you!

Now, as you can see, this Library is heavily developed, and, now, even Demo project not updated to it's Library.

So, here what you can do:

1. **Use old Library version, that works for you.** Update when Demo app updated.
2. **Wait until all this end** - all controls will work. And no bug-reports for a while.

I've emailed developer about scrolling issue, but it's impossible to tell when this will be fixed, as he haven't respond yet.

.

**UPDATE**

This library is ***heavily developed*** - sometimes it is not working, but it will :)

.

Have I answered your question?

Comment: thanks that help me a lots but do you know where i can find the old library please.

Comment: @user3556648 Updated answer. Here is discussion - https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/issues/103